# Can the same Redis instance be used for Sessions and Laravel Queues?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, laravel-5

Is it possible to use the same Redis instance (from AWS) for both Sessions and Queues?

Setting the same redis connection details in the the session and queues config file.

If the Laravel framework does the lottery [2,100] session sweep, deleting old sessions, is it possible that it will interfere with the queues for jobs/listeners?

Comment: as per the document, it should work as the key which is used for session is different from the key used for queues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they can be used for both sessions and queues.  Laravel uses different redis objects for storing session data, cache data and queue data.  You should name your queue something distinct.  Also there is a separation between delayed queue data and immediate queue data within redis.

The Laravel session sweep does not touch the queue data.